# Reduced formula covariance

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We know that there is a reduced formula for the variance, that is $\operatorname{Var}[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$
Is there a reduced formula for the covariance as well? Does the following hold in general?
$\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$Yes, $\Cov(X,Y) = \E[XY] - \E[X]\E[Y]= \E[XY] - \mu_X\mu_Y$ (where $\mu_X = \E[X]$ and $\mu_Y=\E[Y]$). To show this, recall that $$\Cov(X,Y) = \E[(X- \mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)],$$ and expand and simplify.

Comment: Thank you......